# How to plot pandas series' using different contents on the same stacked bar plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to display the following data using the dictionary names (category1, category2 etc) as the y-axis and the float values inside as the x-axis. Using a stacked bar plot, where the total height of each column (category) is the sum of the values inside, and each key name is a separate colour.

```
category1 = {A: 23.5, B: 48, C: 32.4}
category2 = {D: 12, E: 54.3, F: 65}
category2 = {G: 7.5, H: 43, I: 24.8}
```

I hope this makes sense. It's proving very difficult for me to wrap my head around and hence also immensely struggling to google the solution.

Thank you in advance

Comment: what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Nothing. I've spent several hours in the matplotlib docs but can't find anything on building a stacked bar plot where the keys in each bar are different. The only thing I can think is that it might be a case of multiple subplots on one figure, potentially, but that is proving difficult too

Answer (score 2):

Given the data that you provided, this is one way to do it...

```
category1 = {'A': 23.5, 'B': 48, 'C': 32.4}
category2 = {'D': 12, 'E': 54.3, 'F': 65}
category3 = {'G': 7.5, 'H': 43, 'I': 24.8}
df = pd.DataFrame([category1,category2,category3])
df.rename(index = {0:'Category1', 1:'Category2', 2:'Category3'}, inplace=True)
ax = df.plot.barh(stacked=True)
ax.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

**Plot**

[image]

Comment: Amazing, thank you! Follow up question - is there a way to split the legend into separate legends for each category?

Comment: @ben - not sure what you are expecting in terms of split. Perhaps create a new question on what you are expecting?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'level':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'],
        'value':[23.5, 48, 32.4, 12, 54.3, 65, 7.5, 43, 24.8],
        'category':['category1', 'category1', 'category1', 'category2', 'category2', 'category2', 'category2', 'category2', 'category2']
        })
df.set_index('level', inplace=True)
df
###
       value   category
level                  
A       23.5  category1
B       48.0  category1
C       32.4  category1
D       12.0  category2
E       54.3  category2
F       65.0  category2
G        7.5  category2
H       43.0  category2
I       24.8  category2
```

Plot

```
data = df.pivot_table(columns='category', values='value', index='level').T
fig = plt.figure()
color_map = {'A':'#264653', 'B':'#287271', 'C':'#2a9d8f', 'D':'#8ab17d', 'E':'#e9c46a', 'F':'#efb366', 'G':'#f4a261', 'H':'#ee8959', 'I':'#e76f51'}
data.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, figsize=(10,10), color=color_map)
plt.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))
plt.show()
```

[image]